# Добавить GET параметры в Swagger

Tags: python-3.x, django, инспекция-кода, django-rest-framework, swagger

Использую [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) и при использовании [django-rest-swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) для документации методов он не показывает доступные GET параметры и вопрос в том как можно задать?

код:

```
# views.py
@api_view(['GET'])
def tests_api(request):
    """

    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    id = request.query_params.get('id')
    name = request.query_params.get('name')

    return Response({'user': name, 'text': 'Hello world'})

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^api/v1/tests_api/$", tests_api),
]
```

пример http api:

```
GET https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/tests_api/?name=Denis&id=3

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
{
    "user": "Denis",
    "text": "Hello world"
}
```

На данный момент вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но хочу добавить 2 параметра: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Английская](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682278/to-add-get-parameters-in-swagger) версия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из моего старого проекта

```
class CustomView(APIView):

    schema = ManualSchema(fields=[
        coreapi.Field(
            "id",
            required=True,
            location="query",
            schema=coreschema.Integer()
        ),
        coreapi.Field(
            "name",
            required=True,
            location="query",
            schema=coreschema.String()
        ),
    ])

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'user':'ffff', 'token': 'ffff'})
```

Добавляем в схему

```
schema = ManualSchema(fields=[
    coreapi.Field(
        "id",
        required=True,
        location="query",
        schema=coreschema.Integer()
    ),
    coreapi.Field(
        "name",
        required=True,
        location="query",
        schema=coreschema.String()
    ),
])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[документация](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/).

Comment: да, спасибо, это то что нужно, странно что не наткнулся на это в документации, но правда у вас есть лишние параметры, как я понял за это отвечает schema и тут есть документация по нему: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/ и есть возможность задать тип параметра, и если не сложно можете добавьте эту ссылку (на документацию)

Comment: Допустил ошибку, можете заменить `path` на `query`

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/tests_api/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<name>\w+)/$', tests_api),

]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению нужный именно GET параметры, просто получают ответ от Facebook для авторизации и получаю код именно в GET параметрах

Comment: Вот примерно такой url я получаю от Facebook `https://www.domain.com/login?state=text&code=code_123456789`